# "Address already in use" error upon docker-compose up

Tags: docker

I'm trying to start up several docker containers using `docker-compose up`, but I'm getting the following (partial) error message:

```
Recreating 1faf02f5d67e_1faf02f5d67e_1faf02f5d67e_1faf02f5d67e_1faf02f5d67e_ipercroncompose_rabbitmq_1

ERROR: for rabbitmq  Cannot start service rabbitmq: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint ipercroncompose_rabbitmq_1 (a8ded956e30b922289614bbbc4e4fb773c58688d395895b575a88b638592df94): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5672: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Following a suggestion at https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8714, I've tried the command

```
netstat -pna | grep 5672
```

resulting in

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::5672                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    15672    -
```

However, I don't see any process IDs here that I could kill. Any ideas what is causing this error?

Comment: (Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Following https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106561/finding-the-pid-of-the-process-using-a-specific-port, instead of `netstat` I used `lsof -i`:

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~$ sudo lsof -i :5672 | grep LISTEN
[sudo] password for kurt: 
beam.smp 953 rabbitmq   52u  IPv6  33026      0t0  TCP *:amqp (LISTEN)
```

After running `sudo kill 953`, I was able to run the `docker-compose up`.