# Desired port for google cloudSQL connection is not able to be used

Tags: sql, node.js, unix, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am following the steps [here](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-cloud-sql), to setup a CloudSQL DB in Google Cloud Platform. I'm stuck at the step with:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances="[YOUR_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]"=tcp:3306
```

I get the message below:

```
2018/02/07 19:44:10 listen tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: bind: address already in use
```

I've tried: `lsof -i tcp:3306` but nothing shows up. Alternatively, I am able to start a connection to `tcp:3307`, but that's not what's required in the tutorial, and may prevent the rest of the tutorial from working. When I do `lsof -i tcp:3307` however, I am able to see the PID, and kill the SQL connection.

How is the port address 3306 already in use?? Even rebooted my computer.

Comment: That is awkward. I would try using “netstat --listen” to see if it shows a different output. Do you have docker installed? It is possible you are experiencing [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40266556/address-already-in-use-error-upon-docker-compose-up)

Answer (score 3):

### My Steps I took to fix

I stop Mysql on my local machine

```
brew services stop mysql
```

#### But I had a problem of giving a directory for

`Directory to use for placing Unix sockets representing database instances` as seen by the `console` error

Then I did

```
sudo mkdir /cloudsql; sudo chmod 777 /cloudsql
```

#### My Final Script

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=MyInstanceConnName=tcp:3306 -projects=myproject -dir=/cloudsql/
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue, particularly not seeing anything on the specified port. The solution in my particular case was simply to delete the directory that my cloud sql proxies were set up to live in, then create it again. Worked like a charm after that.

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE: After trying to dig through many methods to kill the sql process, find out whats actually running on it, joining the gcloud slack group to ask around, etc etc, I ended up uninstalling mysql, and reinstalling it. Fixed it. :shrug: